# macOS Automator run Expect Script

Tags: macos, automator

How do I run a expect script in macOS Automator?

[image]

As it is possible to see in the picture, there is no such option

its a script of type:

## !/usr/bin/expect

Comment: what do you mean by picture ?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent, thank you for your post but it is more than a little unclear exactly what is going on. What is an "Expect Script?" If you can clarify and tell us (at least) what version of macOS you are running. Any more details on what is happening, what is expected and what troubleshooting steps you have already taken would also be helpful.

Comment: If expect script is some kind of shell, just select sh and invoke the expect script binary before running your command.

Comment: The picture is the headers Automator give me to load with "execute shell script option".

so, i would just select /bin/sh and then how can i run my expect script? i tryed 

select sh in dropdown window and then use "expect /absolute/path/to/my/script.sh" which is an expect script and did not work

Comment: You need to tell `expect` that it will read from a file. Either the shebang should be `#! /usr/bin/expect -f` and called directly or called as `/usr/bin/expect -f /path/to/script`.

Answer (score 1):

[`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) can be called from an Automator action but it must be indirect.

Within your Automator **Run Shell Script** action, call out to `expect` with something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
expect -f /absolute/path/to/expect/script
```

Comment: I tried that but it just does not execute the expect script

Comment: Have you tested `expect`'s exit status? Are you sure the path is correct? Does the command work when issued via Terminal.app? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script/ for help doing this.

Comment: yes, it works fine in terminal, unfortunately, didn't try printing debug messages on Automator, I will try to debug some msg in Automator and reply back